# pass array of an object to webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-get

I have a .net mvc 4 webapi project that I'm trying to pass an array of an object to a method on my controller.

I've found some examples here on SO that talk about needing to set my object's properties with: param1=whatever&param2=bling&param3=blah.

But I don't see how I can pass in a collection using that.

Here is my method signature.  Notice I've decorated the argument with the [FromUri] attribute.

```
public List<PhoneResult> GetPhoneNumbersByNumbers([FromUri] PhoneRequest[] id)
{
    List<PhoneResult> prs = new List<PhoneResult>();
    foreach (PhoneRequest pr in id)
    {
        prs.Add(PhoneNumberBL.GetSinglePhoneResult(pr.PhoneNumber, pr.RfiDate, pr.FinDate, pr.State));
    }
    return prs;
}
```

here is my simple PhoneRequest object:

```
public class PhoneRequest
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string RfiDate { get; set; }
    public string FinDate { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

and here's a sample of what I'm using to pass in:

```
http://localhost:3610/api/phonenumber/getphonenumbersbynumbers/
   [{"PhoneNumber":"8016667777","RfiDate":"","FinDate":"2012-02-11","State":"UT"},
    {"PhoneNumber":"8018889999","RfiDate":"2012-12-01","FinDate":"","State":"UT"}]
```

using this comes back with "bad request"

I also tried this

```
http://localhost:3610/api/phonenumber/getphonenumbersbynumbers?
    id=[{"PhoneNumber":"8016667777","RfiDate":"","FinDate":"2012-02-11","State":"UT"},
        {"PhoneNumber":"8018889999","RfiDate":"2012-12-01","FinDate":"","State":"UT"}]
```

which does reach the method, but the array is null.

how can I pass in an array of my PhoneRequest object to my Web API method?

Comment: As I mentioned in a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962748/pass-array-of-an-object-to-webapi/13963155#comment28579974_13963155) to @Maggie Ying's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13963155/326110), the method name (`getphonenumbersbynumbers`) should **not** be part of the URL in ASP.NET Web API. Instead, the method to use is determined typically by the HTTP verb. See [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try passing the PhoneRequest[] from the uri in this format:

```
http://localhost:3610/api/phonenumber/getphonenumbersbynumbers?
    id[0][PhoneNumber]=8016667777&id[0][FinDate]=2012-02-11&id[0][State]=UT&
    id[1][PhoneNumber]=8018889999&id[1][RfiDate]=2012-12-01&id[1][State]=UT
```

Comment: unfortunately when I put a breakpoint on my method signature, the id is still coming in as null.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Interesting, I was able to get this to model bind correctly...  Have you tried simplified the url a bit (say just `?id[0][State]=UT`) and see if you still get null?

Comment: I tried all sorts of different url strings.  I ended up just having to use jquery.ajax() to pass it in to get it to bind correctly.  I'm sure the people consuming the service can live with that.  Pretty sure it was somethign I did wrong in the sample you provided because I've read several other resources that told me to do the same thing you outlined so I'll mark this as correct...thanks.

Comment: Maggie, that works perfectly for me in the query string, but I just tried doing the same thing in the (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) body of a POST request, but my collection of complex types keeps coming up as an empty collection :( I see during debugging that the type of my collection is `ComplexUriAndFormObject.Models.PhoneRequest[]`, so I would have expected it to work identically for uri or form requests :(

Comment: Oh, also, I should add: When I was trying to get the above to work in my test project, I realized the URL is incorrect. I think that `/getphonenumbersbynumbers` shouldn't be there, right?

Comment: I found the solution to my problem: When `POST`ing an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to Web API, you have to leave off the actual parameter name (in this case, `id`); Since ["only one parameter of an action can come from the request body"](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-1), the parameter name is implied, and must never be provided as part of the form data. Here's my successful request body: `[0][PhoneNumber]=8016667777&[0][FinDate]=2012-02-11&[0][State]=UT&[1][PhoneNumber]=8018889999&[1][RfiDate]=2012-12-01&[1][State]=UT`

Comment: Okay, my problems aren't completely solved, but these comments are getting spammy, so I've created [a new question related to this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19302078/326110)

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you use POST for this.

As you query string grows, you will run into problems with the maximum length of the URL, which is browser dependent.

If you have a lot of parameters to pass, a POST is perfectly acceptable even if you are really only GETting data. What you will lose, however, is the ability for the user to bookmark a particular page with the query string.

Comment: Related to the lack of support for bookmarking, changing `GET`s to `POST`s also prevents uses from trivially using/testing your endpoint from inside a browser. They'll need to author a `POST` request somehow. Sometimes this is convenient and often desired.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom model binder, the [FieldValueModelBinder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/701182/A-Custom-Model-Binder-for-Passing-Complex-Objects) class, which can effectively pass any object containing nested array or generic list types of data with query strings having field-name pairs without imbedding any JSON and XML structures. The model binder can resolve all issues discussed above. Since this question was extended by the question ID [19302078](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302078/passing-complex-type-containing-array-of-complex-types-to-web-api/20790283#20790283), you can see details of my answer in that thread.