# Web API FormURLEncoded media type formatter not working for complex type

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-binding, mediatypeformatter

I have the following ComplexType which I have defined on the PUT action for my controller as follows:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.abc.com/formurl", Name = "ComplexData")]
public class ComplexData {
    [DataMember]         public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]         public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]         public DataExchangeList DataExchange { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.abc.com/formurl", Name = "DataItem")]
public class DataItem {
    [DataMember]         public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]         public string Value { get; set; }
}

[CollectionDataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.abc.com/formurl", Name = "DataExchange")]
public class DataExchangeList : List<DataItem> {
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // PUT api/values
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(ComplexData data)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse<ComplexData>(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
    }
}
```

When trying to pass the ComplexData type on PUT, the collection DataExchange does not bind properly:

```
  PUT http://localhost:53954/api/values HTTP/1.1
  User-Agent: Fiddler
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  Accept: application/xml
  Host: localhost:53954
  Content-Length: 106
  Id=123456789&Name=Complex&DataExchange[0][Name]=Data&DataExchange[0][Value]=ComplexType
```

The response which simply returns back the data shows the collection is empty:

```
  <ComplexData xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://schemas.abc.com/formurl">
    <DataExchange />
    <ID>123456789</ID>
    <Name>Complex</Name>
  </ComplexData>
```

Isn't this supposed to work with the FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter?

Is there anything wrong with the way I'm passing the Collection data as follows?

**DataExchange[0][Name]=Data&DataExchange[0][Value]=ComplexType**

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Sid

Comment: What is wrong with this? The response you are getting correct right??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing complex type containing array of complex types to Web API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302078/passing-complex-type-containing-array-of-complex-types-to-web-api)

Comment: Jon, that custom model binder solution looks great. But, if I understand correctly, it forces all data passed to controller to be in the query string format. My clients still need support for the JSON and XML media type formatters in Web API. This issue is just to resolve the binding when Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I guess what I'm looking at is customizing the default FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter to support the complex collection model?

Comment: I've got a similar issue too http://stackoverflow.com/q/22203989/1796