# ASP.NET Web API multiple post messages single controller or action

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-web-api

So I have the following issue:

We have a scenario where a third party is sending post messages to our server, we have no control over that, and they want to send everything to a single url, so we can not do anything regarding query parameters, so my question then is, is it possible to handle different post messages with a single action. In essence the content of the post message will define what needs to happen with said request.

Post message 1:

```
<xml>
    <content1> content </content1>
    <content2> content </content2>
</xml>
```

Post message 2:

```
<xml>
    <content1> content </content1>
    <content3> content </content3>
</xml>
```

As you can see some of the messages will have similar properties.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it possible to send both messages in one post call using the technique of parameter binding? Something as described here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302078/passing-complex-type-containing-array-of-complex-types-to-web-api/20790283#20790283

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following signature to accept arbitrary XML content,

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]XElement xmlbody) { 
    // Process the xmlbody 
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created); 
}
```

I have more details about this kind of raw media type processing [here](http://www.bizcoder.com/posting-raw-json-to-web-api).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.
Specify your action to have a string input parametre. That way you can get the entire message as a string and not worry about its properties... 
However, you will need to implement the logic in the controller to diferentiate messages.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyActionForAllMessages(string message)
{
    //Your logic
}
```

Comment: You can't use string as a parameter type to do that.  See here http://bizcoder.com/posting-raw-json-to-web-api for why.