# Asp.net Web API - Post complex type to get data or get using query string

Tags: post, get, asp.net-web-api, complextype

I just want to clarify if it would be ok to use POST method to get some data from the Web API. The scenario is that the user has to pass a complex type e.g a UserInfo which has ID, Department, ETC to a Web Api function to get some extra details about user.

I can do this by passing the details in URI e.g http://apiuri/User?ID=1&Department=ABC& XXX and using a GET method or I can use a POST method and pass the UserInfo to it.

I prefer Post method however there are arguments in the team that Post should only be used for Creating or Modifying resources.

Is this correct? Should Post only be used for Creating/modifying a resource only?

many thanks

Comment: Good question - exactly what I'm looking for right now. The answer below is correct, but still leaves open - what to do in this case? What is best practice when you have a complex query - long complex GET string or a POST to a method that doesn't change data? Neither are a good solution, both have their pros and cons

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302078/passing-complex-type-containing-array-of-complex-types-to-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Typically Post methods are not guaranteed to be idempotent i.e. they can yield different results at different times. Now, this is not the case with your scenario. But without a wsdl, people really look to standards to figure out how a service would work. If you don't follow the standards, you might have a harder time explaining your api to your clients.

Comment: Hi Yasir, thanks for the reply. But I don't think you answered my question. Can we use Post in any other scenario that does not require a resource modification/addition? ... How about a situation where you want to validate a user and then display some sensitive information back. E.g the user passes User name and password to be authenticated, once authentication happens then we display to user some sensitive information. There is not resource changes here but i don't think Get is an appropriate method here.