# Pass Collection of objects to Get method of Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, web

I tried passing collection of objects fromuri in Post method of Webapi. I would like to do the same using the Get method. Is it possible

Comment: In a GET you can use the querystring to get data to your API, but I would only use that for a limitid amout of values.

Comment: In GET you can send only limited data that to as URL parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there might be a solution described in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962748/pass-array-of-an-object-to-webapi)
question.

But I personally do not consider this as a good idea, because a request string has size limitations and url made in such kind of fashion does not seem user friendly.